# Easy 1st - yes title is a hint

Tags: wordplay, story

1 1

Y

1 1 2

2 1 4

4 2 1 3 2

HINT:

> This may just be as easy as it looks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tags say wordplay and story, so here's the story -

> **Easy 1st**
>
>  One won.
>  Why?
>  One won [over] two.
>  Two won [over] four.
>  for Two won [over] Three too.
>
>  So it's some kind of a race with the first place going to "One", second place to "Two".

Comment: @nicael, You're right. This answer probably doesn't make sense then.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for... My apologies if I missed tagged... I'll leave for now until a vote or edit... GJ and +1 on the anser @nicael

Comment: @Mega Lol, I really didn't suppose that you've meant to ask about the story, it looked more like a riddle.

Comment: I should add that the order in which the 'racers' finished was One,Two,Three, Four respectively. Three finishing before Four is only observable through deduction...

Comment: @MegaMark, I'm sure my interpretation of the last line is probably slightly different than yours.

Comment: Ha, I was thinking something along these lines but I couldn't figure out the [over] part.

Comment: By saying "Two won Four because Two won Three"   implies that Three finished prior to Four... so, 

One beat Two
Two beat Four because Two beat Three too.... but yeah... you nailed it regardless

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> light

Thoughts:

> The shape which is made by the numbers and `Y` in the current position *looks* like "L". A hint tells to *look*, and also says it's *easy* (*weak* in a possible interpretation). `Y` is the sound similar to "AI" sometimes. Mentioning the title makes to think of `T`.

Comment: I like this... but I simply didn't have the cunning and craftsmanship to go that deep... the title "Easy 1st" I thought was cleaver because this is my 1st post... and it's also a clue!!! XD